# interval of animation fadeIn fadeOut

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I was looking around for solution of my problem and tried to solve it with animation css3 or setInterval but with no effect

**WHAT I WANT ACCOMPLISH?**

I want to make this animation as loader, it mean's loop it indefinitely
This is logo which i want to fadeIn and Out one by one clockwise.

Why setInterval does not work? 
Because each animation is with dealay and each repeat delay does not apply.

```
function runIt() {
    var time = 600;
    $(".first").fadeIn(time).fadeOut(time);
    $(".second").delay(time).fadeIn(time).fadeOut(time);
    $(".third").delay(time*2).fadeIn(time).fadeOut(time);
    $(".fourth").delay(time*3).fadeIn(time).fadeOut(time);
   };
runIt();
```

[EXAMPLE CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/SzymonDziewonski/pen/dGkaD)

**Any help would be appreciate a LOT! :)**

**SOLUTION FOR ALL WHO WILL HAVE SAME PROBLEM:**

```
            function runIt() {
                var time = 600;
                $(".first").fadeIn(time).fadeOut(time, function(){
                    $(".second").fadeIn(time).fadeOut(time, function(){
                        $(".third").fadeIn(time).fadeOut(time, function(){
                            $(".fourth").fadeIn(time).fadeOut(time, runIt); 
                        });
                    });
                });



            };
            runIt();
```

Comment: Now that you have edited it, the reason your `setInterval` doesn't work is that you don't have `setInterval` in your code.

Comment: Anyway it was wrong, thats why I ask community for help:)

Comment: Downvote me for what? I didnt include also example with css3 animtion and yet it was ok... setInterval function is canceled cuz it is wrong. So why it should mess you in head with wrong code?

Comment: When you ask why `setInterval` doesn't work, you should include the code you were using so people can answer that question.  Without the code, no one can tell you why it didn't work.

Comment: fadeIn and fadeOut methods accept callback

Comment: @JamesMontagne I put it back, is that ok right now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `setInterval`, but probably a cleaner solution would be to call `runIt` again from the callback of the final animation:

```
function runIt() {
    var time = 600;
    $(".first").fadeIn(time).fadeOut(time);
    $(".second").delay(time).fadeIn(time).fadeOut(time);
    $(".third").delay(time*2).fadeIn(time).fadeOut(time);
    $(".fourth").delay(time*3).fadeIn(time).fadeOut(time, runIt); // call runIt when fadeOut completes
};
runIt();
```

Comment: Indeed that is nice solution

Answer (score 1):

SetInterval works. You need to call the function before the interval starts:

```
runIt();

setInterval(function() {
  runIt();
}, 3600);
```

CodePen example [here](http://cdpn.io/dGkaD).

Comment: should be time*8 not time*6, because it should wait for the animation to end before restarting, so 'setInterval(function() { runIt(); }, 4800);'

Comment: now look how its work.. and I think it works pretty bad. After fourth element star second and there is mess ..